# biblatex: inherit data annotations?

Tags: biblatex

Is it possible to inherit data annotations with crossref? I'd like to give certain fields a "language" annotation so I can apply the relevant polyglossia macros. But they don't seem to inherit by default and I can't figure out how to change that.

Here is a minimal (non-)working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
    style=authoryear,%
  ]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
  @collection{foo,
    editor = {John Doe},
    date = {2000-01-01},
    title = {The Title},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    publisher+an = {="Publisher Annotation"},
  }

  @incollection{bar,
    crossref = {foo},
    author = {Jane Doe},
    title = {The Other Title},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\getfieldannotation[publisher]}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! You don't want to use `language`?

Comment: If annotations were fields, you could alter the data inheritance setup so `incollection` inherited the annotation from `collection`, but they aren't stored as fields but as annotations and I'm not sure you can inherit annotations?

Comment: This does not appear to be supported at the moment. A related feature for inheritance of `@xdata` annotations was recently added to the dev version (see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1327#issuecomment-1874972363), but normal data inheritance still does not appear to take into account annotations. Open a feature request at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues.

Comment: @cfr I want to be able to deal appropriately with e.g. articles in a different language than the journal/collection, or multilingual publications with an official title in each language.

Comment: @moewe Thank you!

Comment: It would be useful for `author` (and similar fields), actually. Right now, I put Babel mark up directly into the value of the field when necessary, but this isn't ideal and, as you say, the language may need to be different for different fields. (I'm guessing the author case is even more common than the multiple-title case since all kinds of names author fields in various languages.) If you post a feature request, can you post a link here?

Comment: The feature request is now at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1344.

Comment: Will be implemented/fixed in Biber 2.20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needed an adjustment in Biber that was added in version 2.20 released just a couple of days ago. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1344 for more details.

The MWE now produces

[image: Doe, Jane (Jan. 1, 2000). “The Other Title”. In: The Title. Ed. by John Doe. PublisherPublisher Annotation Doe, John, ed. (Jan. 1, 2000). The Title. PublisherPublisher Annotation]

with the annotation in both entries.